# UICollectionView: Get indexPath of Cell that is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with several cells – there are always some of them outside the viewport, so there are cells being reused.

When an event occurs I want to take a specific cell and move it to the front of the `UICollectionView`. In order to make `moveItemAtIndexPath()` work I need to know the current `indexPath` of the Cell that I want to move.

When I initialize the Cells in the `CollectionViewDelegate` with the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method I save its `indexPath` into a variable of the Object that is the model of the Cell (not it’s actual Object, just the model). Then I look at this variable when I want to move the cell.

This is working fine as long as the cell was visible once – it seems like it only initiated then, even though it is part of the `CollectionViewData` all the time.

How can I make sure my `CollectionViewCell` has an `indexPath`, even when it is not visible or has not been visible yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what data (cell) you want to present at the front (I assume top) of your `UICollectionView`, why don't you just update your `dataSource` and reload your `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Because I want the animation of the cell moving to the front. When I just update the `dataSource` it just appears at the front.

Comment: However I am now using `indexOfObject()` to find the Objects position in my `dataSource` (which is always the same as the `indexPath.item` property. This way it always works. Thanks!